# Insert Data in a popup modal and refresh data in the parent

Tags: javafx

I have a window in JavaFX, which contains a `TableView`. When I click on it, it opens a modal pop-up window. In these window you can insert data and submit it in a database.

Each window has its FXML controller.

I want to refresh the tableview embedded in the parent window of the popup. Do I have to use the `focused` property of the parent window ? I don't know which event to use or which method to call between controllers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a MVC pattern, I would suggest you to:

- Create a model where you instantiate your database; that database will be an `ObservableList<CustomItem>`, where `CustomItem` is the data container representing a line of your table.
- In your model, create an `updateItem` method which changes information for one item of the list
- Link your `TableView` to the list using `tableView.setItems(obsList)`
- In your pop-up window, create a <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd> button; the `setOnAction` method of that button will call `updateItem(CustomItem yourSelectedItem)`. Then your `TableView` will be automatically updated.

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I don't use MVC. I have a code file behind all my windows. And these file manage all the window.

Comment: Do you have a model for your application?

Comment: Yes I have a model. But it won't respect the pattern MVC

Comment: I think you should provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to clarify the request.